# javascript subtracting from input text and displaying to div

Tags: javascript

here's my sample code

[Here is my jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/intheb0x/ch7akhjz/)

my problem is when i try to empty the input text the output is not correct...i dont know what to do anymore please help

```
$("#xx").keyup(function(){
    var res = $(this).val();
    $('.type').text(res);
    res = parseInt(res);

    var dd = $('.hid').val();

    dd = parseInt(dd);

    var total;

    //add
    // total = res+dd;

    // if(isNaN(total)){
    //  $('.dd').text('100');
    // } else {
    //  $('.dd').text(total);
    // }

    //subtract
    total = dd - res;
    if(isNaN(total)){
        $('.hid').val();            
    } else {
        if(!$(this).val() || $(this).val() === ""){
            $('.hid').val();
        } else {
            $('.dd').text(total);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean the output is "not correct"? Could you tell us what you expect, and what the actual output is? As well as what you hope for your code to do, and any errors you might be getting? Please refer to the FAQ before asking questions.

Comment: You start with a value of `2000` in your div element, but the value you are actually subtracting from, from your hidden input, is `20000` …

Comment: I am sure that you hope someone would read and figure out your problem, but that is not in the spirit of this site. Being aware of your problem, and asking for clear help, is an important part of Q&A here

Comment: sorry i just updated my jsfiddle codes...everytime i input the answer is okay my problem is when i erase my input the answer goes wrong

Comment: That still doesn't tell us what the answer should be

Comment: I expect the correct answer to be 20000 since there is nothing in the input when you erase the values in the input box and subtracting nothing from 20000 means the result is 20000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example, I had made changes in html take care of that:

```
$(function(){
    $("#xx").on('input', function(e){ //A
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); //B
        var b = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
        var a = parseInt($("#hid").val()) || 0;
        $("#type").text(b);
        $("#dd").text(a - b);
    });
})
```

- A: event will be captured on keypress and also for copy-paste.
- B: remove non-numeric characters from the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution from your code. Add `res=isNaN(res) ? 0 : res;` before performing the subtraction.

Here is the fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/ch7akhjz/1/